# How to Query Equal/Non-Equal Values Across Multiple Columns in a Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am fairly new to SQL and I had a question about querying across multiple columns with equal/not equal values.
I need to pull results where values in

```
Column A = Column A AND Column B = Column B AND Column is NOT equal to Column C.
```

Does anyone know if something like this is possible? Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't make sense :S, do you want to join the table to itself? ColumnA will always be equal to ColumnA like 1 will always be equal to 1 .

Comment: Sorry, guess I should clarify.  I need to pull data where the values in ColA are equal, where the values in ColB are equal, and the values in ColC are not equal.  Thanks.

Comment: Equal to what? Of course it will be equal to itself

Comment: Equal to other values in the row.  For example, the query should only pull the first two rows from the example data below:                          ColA ColB ColC
xxx aaa 111
xxx aaa 222
xxx bbb 222
yyy ccc 333
zzz ddd 333

Answer (score 1):

```
Column A = Column A AND Column B = Column B AND Column != Column C.
```

or

```
Column A = Column A AND Column B = Column B AND Column <> Column C.
```

Anyway, it would help if you add your table specification.

Comment: Use <> instead != (that isn't compatible with some DMBS)

Answer (score 0):

Example using not <> and = :-

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl2.content 
FROM tbl1 ,tbl2 
WHERE tbl1.creationTime LIKE '2012-06-28%' AND tbl1.creationTime <> tbl2.updateTime
and tbl1.id=tbl2.id
```

Comment: What does he have to do with `LIKE` ?

Comment: just an example as the user mentioned he is new to SQL.

Comment: And do you think he will suddenly get advanced and will understand what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join :-Self-joins are used to compare values in a column with other values in the same column in the same table

SELECT *
FROM table1 a1, table1 a2
WHERE (a1.ColumnA  = a2.ColumnA  AND a1.ColumnB  = a2.ColumnB ) <> a2.Column C;